# How to remove trailing slash from Internet Explorer?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I am getting an issue of trailing slash in end of url(only in Internet Explorer). For example if i type  http://www.google.com IE convert it to http://www.google.com/ (trailing slash at end of url). Is there any solution to resolve this in asp.net mvc? This problem occurs only in IE.

Comment: Welcome, but please explain why this looks like a problem to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue, this is how IE displays URLs. Why do you need the slash gone?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, actually its the requirement of person for whom i am working. So is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is it required to simply not DISPLAY the slash in IE bar or do you save that URL as a string and process it later on? Because I don't believe the first one is even possible. It also seriously interests me why does your client even bother with such stuff?

Comment: yeah, it just required not to DISPLAY the slash in IE only.

Comment: How is that a problem? It doesn't impact literally anything. Like above, I don't believe it's even possible.

Comment: yeah, but it just the requirement, and i want to be sure before making reply to that person.